# Making FA change color on :hover with <li>

Tags: html, css, colors, hover, font-awesome

I'm currently working on the basis of a side navigation bar which will be enabled by the old hamburger button.

```css
/* * Navigation Menu
   * The Hambuger will open this 
   *

*/

.navigation-container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 240px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  border-right: 2px solid #252525;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.navigation {
  width: 80%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.navigation ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 90px; 
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.navigation ul li {
  /* Setting the area */
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px 0px;
  /* Typography changes */
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #DDDDDD;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: 1.5px;
  /* Extra Styling */
  border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
  -webkit-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  transition: .25s ease-in-out;
}

.navigation ul .fa {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding-right: 5px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #DDDDDD;
}

.navigation-container, .navigation li, > li {
  color: #252525;
}

.navigation ul li:hover {
  padding: 35px 0px;
  color: #252525;
  -webkit-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  transition: .25s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">

  <title>Aaron Ward's Portfolio</title>

  <!-- Stylesheet links -->
   <!-- Font Awesome -->
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

   <!-- Open Sans Typeface Import -->
   <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700,800,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

   <!-- Personal stylesheets -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

</head>

<body>

<!-- NAVIGATION START -->
<div class="navigation-container">
 <div class="navigation">
  <ul>
   <a href="">
    <li>
     <i class="fa fa-home fa-fw"></i></span>
     HOME
    </li>
   </a>

   <a href="">
    <li>
     <i class="fa fa-connectdevelop fa-fw"></i>
     WORK
    </li>
   </a>

   <a href="">
    <li>
     <i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i>
     ABOUT
    </li>
   </a>

   <a href="">
    <li>
     <i class="fa fa-envelope fa-fw"></i>
     CONTACT
    </li>
   </a>
  </ul>
 </div>
</div>

</body>
```

As you can see when hovering over the [ul li] element's, the font-awesome icon is not changing color.

I have tried adding the following (results didn't work):

```
.navigation ul li:hover, .navigation ul .fa:hover {
  padding: 35px 0px;
  color: #252525;
  -webkit-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  transition: .25s ease-in-out;
}

.navigation ul .fa:hover {
color: #252525;
}
```

but clearly this wouldn't work as I want the whole area to effect both elements (FA & the

text color.

**So ultimately:
How do I make both the text and Font awesome icon change color when hovering over the respected ul li element**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a problem with your markup, `<a>` should be inside `<li>`. And `<li>` must be directly under `<ul>`, you can fix it all together once.

```css
a:hover {
  color: red;
}

/* if the above code didn't work for you
a:hover, a:hover .fa {
  color: green;
}
*/

/* if the above code didn't work for you
a:hover, a:hover .fa::before {
  color: blue;
}
*/
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <i class="fa fa-home fa-fw"></i>
      HOME
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have managed to place the <a> inside the <li> (I thought something was odd). However, I am now having the issue of this: http://prntscr.com/6tv69d     (the text is not changing color, only the icon)

Comment: @user3063286 I have updated the answer again, it seems it can be fixed all together as simple as that, forget about the pseudo thing for now.

Comment: Ok, I have updated it and I'm basically back to square one without the padding now taking place. http://prntscr.com/6tv9pz (result) http://prntscr.com/6tv9zg (html & css). Thank you for the help by the way.  PS added a codepen to make life easy: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MYNEBm

Comment: @user3063286 use `.navigation li a:hover, .navigation li a:hover .fa {...}`, that's it, demo - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qEePyM

Answer (score 0):

THIS CSS:

```
.navigation ul li:hover, .navigation ul li:hover .fa {
  padding: 35px 0px;
  color: #252525;
  -webkit-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  transition: .25s ease-in-out;
}
```

.....

```css
/* * Navigation Menu
   * The Hambuger will open this 
   *

*/

.navigation-container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 240px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  border-right: 2px solid #252525;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.navigation {
  width: 80%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
.navigation ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 90px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
.navigation ul li {
  /* Setting the area */
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px 0px;
  /* Typography changes */
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #DDDDDD;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: 1.5px;
  /* Extra Styling */
  border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
  -webkit-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  transition: .25s ease-in-out;
}
.navigation ul .fa {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding-right: 5px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #DDDDDD;
}
.navigation-container,
.navigation li,
> li {
  color: #252525;
}
.navigation ul li:hover {
  padding: 35px 0px;
  color: #252525;
  -webkit-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  transition: .25s ease-in-out;
}
.navigation ul li:hover,
.navigation ul li:hover .fa {
  padding: 35px 0px;
  color: #252525;
  -webkit-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  transition: .25s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">

  <title>Aaron Ward's Portfolio</title>

  <!-- Stylesheet links -->
  <!-- Font Awesome -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

  <!-- Open Sans Typeface Import -->
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700,800,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

  <!-- Personal stylesheets -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

</head>

<body>

  <!-- NAVIGATION START -->
  <div class="navigation-container">
    <div class="navigation">
      <ul>
        <a href="">
          <li>
            <i class="fa fa-home fa-fw"></i>
            </span>
            HOME
          </li>
        </a>

        <a href="">
          <li>
            <i class="fa fa-connectdevelop fa-fw"></i>
            WORK
          </li>
        </a>

        <a href="">
          <li>
            <i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i>
            ABOUT
          </li>
        </a>

        <a href="">
          <li>
            <i class="fa fa-envelope fa-fw"></i>
            CONTACT
          </li>
        </a>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: im still having issues, but trying to figure them out with the top comment at the moment as I first took root with that concept

Answer (score 0):

Move the ":hover" selector to the tag that you're actually going to be hovering over. Then specify the child elements you want affected so it takes this form.

```
#parent:hover #child {
   /* ... */
}
```

So your selectors should look like this (About).

```
.navigation ul li:hover {
      padding: 35px 0px;
      color: #252525;
      -webkit-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
      -moz-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
      -o-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
      transition: .25s ease-in-out;
}

.navigation ul:hover .fa {
      color: #252525;
}
```